# Javascript - Setting 2 properties to same value - console log shows they have different value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looping through an array of documents and setting two properties to the same value, however, doing a `console.log` shows the two properties have different values.

code:

```
this.logicItem.$promise.then(() => {
    this.logicItem.getDocuments().$promise.then((docs: any) => {
        docs.forEach(element => {
            if (element.buildProgrammeActivityStatus === BUILD_PROGRAMME_ACTIVITY_STATUS.Confirmed ||
                element.buildProgrammeActivityStatus === BUILD_PROGRAMME_ACTIVITY_STATUS.Complete) {
                element.upper = true;
                element.canUpload = true;
            } else {
                element.upper = false;
                element.canUpload = false;
            }
        });
        console.log(docs);
    });
    this.logicItem.reload(true);
});
```

When the code sets both properties to `true`, console logging the whole array shows that `canUpload` is always false no matter what, and `upper` is true if the code entered the `true` block. What could cause this bizarre behavior? I have tried it using `array.map()` and some other forms of looping, all with the same result.

Comment: Is `canUpload` writable? `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, 'canUpload') || Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(element), 'canUpload'))`

Comment: @AuxTaco Thank you. the console log shows `{value: true, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}`. Looks like it is writable. Very strange that it isn't changing the value then.

Answer (score 0):

The forEach statement should work fine. I tried to call it with some dummy data and I got the expected behavior in all cases. Have you tried to log each element in the forEach statement? If so the problem reproduce? Are the elements as expected? 
Also what is the reload function does?

Comment: Console.logging `element` directly after setting both properties to `true` shows that `canUpload` is false and `upper` is true. I think the code is fine so will not reproduce this error in a sandbox. I'm more asking what I should look into. I think my `canUpload` property must somehow be `readOnly` or something.

Comment: Are the fields `canUpload ` and  `upper` defined before the function? If so are both false? I would also just try to change the value of `canUpload` to true in the loop to to confirm that is not changing (maybe also outside) .

Comment: `upper` is not defined initially but `canUpload` is false initially. `docs[0].canUpload = true; console.log(docs);` showed that it was still `false`.

Comment: What does `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, 'canUpload');` returns?

 
(To be more specific try to store the value in an variable `const elementDescriptor = getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, 'canUpload');` then log the `elementDescriptor .writable` property )

Comment: If writable is false, that is the reason is not working. So in that case you need to check the configurable property also (you can just log the hole getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, 'canUpload'); since it has 4 properties). If the configurable and writable are both false I am afraid that according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), if the configurable attribute is false, you can only change writable attribute from true to false (and any other attribute, including configurable)

Answer (score 0):

Array.foreach simply runs through an array and does not change the value of array. Array.map runs through the entire array and returns a new array but does not change the array itself you need to manually assign or rewrite the variable.
So here is my suggestion

```
this.logicItem.$promise.then(() => {
this.logicItem.getDocuments().$promise.then((docs: any) => {
    //changed from forEach to map
    docs = docs.map( element => {
        if (element.buildProgrammeActivityStatus === BUILD_PROGRAMME_ACTIVITY_STATUS.Confirmed ||
            element.buildProgrammeActivityStatus === BUILD_PROGRAMME_ACTIVITY_STATUS.Complete) {
            element.upper = true;
            element.canUpload = true;
        } else {
            element.upper = false;
            element.canUpload = false;
        }
        //Added a return element
        return element.
    });
    console.log(docs);
});
this.logicItem.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and it has the same result. Also `array.forEach` does change the value of `upper`. The `console.log` shows this.

Comment: Strange behavior. Last resort try using 1 for true and 0 for false.  This might not be helpful, but says otherwise on Array.forEach Vs Array.map. 

    `let b = [1,2,3,4,5];
    b.forEach( b => b * 2 );
   b Result =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   b.map( b => b * 2 )
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
Result b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
b = b.map( b => b * 2 )
result b =[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

Comment: Changing canUpload to 1 and 0 did not work. That example you gave is correct as I tested it. But this is also correct: `b = [{a: true, b: true}, {a: true, b: true}]` then `b.forEach( x => { x.a = false; x.b = false });` then console.log(b); is `[{a: false, b: false}, {a: false, b: false}]`

Comment: You are right on changing the property of an object via foreach. Thanks for the heads up.